# ion-menu dynamically change direction

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5, ionic6, ion-menu

I am using ionic 6.
I have ion-menu that don't change his direction with the app direction.
I changed the direction of the app with `document.documentElement.setAttribute('dir', 'rtl')` and the ion-menu side is "start", but he still open up like rtl.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

class YourComponent{

   constructor(
     @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document
   ){}

   onDirectionChange(){
     if (yourCondition)
       this.document.documentElement.dir = 'rtl';
     else{
       this.document.documentElement.dir = 'ltr';
     }
   }

}
```

This will change whole app's direction including ion-menu.

Comment: ion-menu direction still don't change

Comment: can you make stackblitz with minimal reproduction.

Comment: I have, but the problem is this work on web but doesn't work on mobile, do you no if there is a why in stackblitz to do so?